# UWP key shortcut to run app

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp

I am currently swimming (drowning) into the MSDN, searching for an anwser for this problem :

Like OneNote, I want my Universal Windows App to listen to a shortcut.
Then run something, and display results.

So I found this about [Launching, resuming, and background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt227652.aspx)
But I couldn't find something about listening to keyboards shortcuts.

So I searched among classes, and found the [BackgroundTaskBuilder Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskbuilder.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1).
But it looks like the SetTrigger Method[1] doesn't register shortcuts.

There's also this thing of Launching an app for results [2]. I can't realize how it can help me.

I know how to listen to shortcuts when I am focusing the window of my program, BUT how can I do that when I am not ?
I think it has to be a service running in background, and listening to that shortcut event. But I can't find that in the doc...

I would appreciate some help and suggestions, thank you guys

[1] : msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskbuilder.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1

[2]: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt269386.aspx

Comment: I believe OneNote uses a separate non-UWP process for this (the "Send to OneNote Tool" that is listed in the Startup tab of Task Manager) - this may then start the UWP app. Bear in mind that not all UWP platforms have keyboards to listen to keyboard shortcuts from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this with the current SDK. You can only manually add shortcut to your app to the desktop and taskbar and set it to be launched with a shortcut, like any other Windows app.